# Why do all questions appear as answered?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

As of today, all questions appear like they have already been answered (eg. filled green hexagon).

[image: filled hexagons on unanswered questions]

Is that a bug or some design change? I think it's rather confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's Christmas. You have to unwrap the question before you know if it's answered :)

No, this was a plain ol' bug. Fixed.